# Using a instance method my tabbar controller didn't work?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

1.I like to create tabBarItem as programatically.

2.how to make it as dynamically is it possible?

3.below code i have tried that to make dynamically but can't.

4.i have created the tabbarcontroller and stored view controller into array.

problem:
when i am assign that array of view controller to tabbarcontroller its get crashed.

.m file

```
       UITabBarController *tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [arrController addObject:subview];
    if([[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"name"] count]>0)
    {
        for(int i;[[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"name"] count]>i;i++)
        {
            NSString *category = [arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"category"];
            NSLog(@"arrSubCategory%@",[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"category"]);
            int categoryId = [category intValue];
            subview.tabBarItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrFullSubCategory objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]] image:Nil tag:categoryId];
//            subview.tabBarItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"kishore" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
            NSLog(@"because of for loop");
        }
    }
    tab.viewControllers=arrController;
    tab.view.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:tab.view];
```

**Instance Method:**

```
+(dataHandler *)getDataHandler
{

    dispatch_once(&internalOnceToken,^{
        internalInstance = [[dataHandler alloc] init];
        if(internalInstance) {
            NSLog(@"Internal instance created: %@", internalInstance);
        }
    });
    if(internalOnceToken == -1) {
        NSLog(@"Internal instance exists: %@", internalInstance);//code=2,address=0X7fff5cal0fe4
    }
    return internalInstance;

}
```

**Error:**

```
code=2,address=0X7fff5cal0fe4
```

**Output**

```
2015-09-09 16:28:11.575 [4011:139265] Internal instance exists: <dataHandler: 0x7fdb1ae260b0>
2015-09-09 16:28:11.575 [4011:139265] system sub category result(
        {
        category = 35;
        image = "images/Hatchback.jpg";
        name = Hatchback;
        parent = 20;
    },
        {
        category = 36;
        image = "images/Sedan.jpg";
        name = Sedan;
        parent = 20;
    },
        {
        category = 37;
        image = "images/SUV.jpg";
        name = SUV;
        parent = 20;
    }
)
2015-09-09 16:28:11.576 [4011:139265] Internal instance exists: <dataHandler: 0x7fdb1ae260b0>
2015-09-09 16:28:11.576 [4011:139265] system sub category result(
        {
        category = 35;
        image = "images/Hatchback.jpg";
        name = Hatchback;
        parent = 20;
    },
        {
        category = 36;
        image = "images/Sedan.jpg";
        name = Sedan;
        parent = 20;
    },
        {
        category = 37;
        image = "images/SUV.jpg";
        name = SUV;
        parent = 20;
    }
)
```

like a for loop its get run at a particular time its get crashed ,anybody please help me to find out the issues .

Comment: that subview is its own class...... @iosDevelopers

Comment: no @PriyaPatel , i like to display the title in tabbar its from json response..

Comment: do you have any idea to create infinite tabbar....@PriyaPatel

Comment: i have everything mentioned in the question ,go to instance method in that right side you will see the error ,but in stack no error get printed @PriyaPatel

Comment: that data running like a for loop infinite time and finally get crashed...